# How do I preserve special characters loaded from JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, special-characters

For example in my JSON file I have the character "ä". But when loaded in my html it doesn't render. Do I have to add something to the Ajax?

```
$.ajax({
        url: "json/content.json",
        data: "nocache=" + Math.random(),
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(source){
            data = source;
            showInfo();
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert("Failed to load content");
        }
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think u need to edit <meta charset=""/> tag in your html page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a charset issue, json has no problem with special characters.
Make sure that the charsets between the server reply and the html page displaying it match.